# How do i prevent my code from accepting decimals, and only whole numbers

Tags: c

So i'm trying to do a check if the user inputs a decimal value the code would print out invalid value and ask for another value. any ideas?
really new to c-code any guide or tips would be loved.
i'm guessing its something to do with "value" *2, if the value is an even number true, else false.
if i'm right or wrong please tell me so, the issue is i don't know how to put it in code

```
     do
        {
        printf("\nEnter value for 1st side of the Triangle: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d%*c", &side1);

        if((side1 <= 0) || (side1 > 999))
        {
            printf ("Invalid Value, Retry Input\n");
            fflush(stdin);
        }
        if ((side1 >= 1) && (side1 < 999))
        {
            printf("Enter value for 2nd side of the Triangle: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d%*c", &side2); 
        }   

        if ((side2 < 0) || (side2 > 999))
        {
            printf ("Invalid Value, Retry Input\n");
            fflush(stdin);
        }
        if ((side2 >= 1) && (side2 < 999))
        {
            printf("Enter value for 3rd side of the Triangle: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d%*c", &side3);
        }

        if ((side3 < 0) || (side3 > 999))
        {
            printf ("Invalid Value, Retry Input\n");
            fflush(stdin);
        }
        if ((side3 >= 1) && (side3 < 999))
        { 
            success = 1;
        }   
        }
        while(success == 0);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and a ask a question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You should not use `fflush(stdin)` for any reason. `fflush` is only defined by the standard for use in output streams (e.g. `stdout`) and update streams when the most recent operation was not input. Using it on an input stream (e.g. `stdin`) is undefined behavior, meaning anything (or nothing) could happen depending on where you compile and run your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try reading in a string and using strtol to convert it to an integer. Then check **endptr to see if it received a bad value (float).